# M-h not working on Mac (minimizes window instead of org-mark-element)

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, osx

Using Mac OS Big Sur, org-mode 9.2.6 with GNU Emacs 27.2. I am trying to mark the whole item under the point. But when I use the `M-h` keystroke, the Emacs windows disappears and I need to click its icon in the dock to make it visible again. To check if I used the correct keystroke, I ran `C-h w org-mark-element` and got `M-h` back. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `C-h k M-h` tell you? If `M-h` is being grabbed by your OS or something else outside Emacs, then you won't see a description of it in `*Help*` from `C-h k`. That'll suggest that it's not an Emacs problem; it's a problem elsewhere.

Comment: @Drew There's no way to complete the command because the window disappears as soon as I press `M-h`.

Comment: That sounds like an indication that something outside Emacs is intercepting that key. Check your OS or window manager or whatever for its configuration of "hotkeys" or whatever.

Comment: See [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/66771/how-can-i-override-an-os-key-binding-in-emacs) for another manifestation of this problem on a different OS. You'll either have to bind the function to a different key that is not used by your OS or somehow convince your OS to not hijack that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you are using the emacs-mac "distribution".

The only solution I have found so far is to rebind `cmd-h` (M-h in Emacs) in:
System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts.

I rebind the menu item "Hide Emacs" (Type it in exactly like it appears in the menu bar) to `shift-ctrl-option-cmd-h`.

That should free up `cmd-h`.

Comment: That worked! The only change I had to make was to manually choose the "Emacs" app from the "App Shortcuts" screen, since it wasn't already listed there.